# Is there a way to lift out an item from the recyclerview and move it to another layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop

I want to create  a recyclerview that can drag the seleced items out of the recycler view

I tried various github solutions,but it is only to move from one recyclerview to another.
I need to drag the items to a button,and when the item reaches it,it shows a bottom sheet dialog and then I need to insert it to a recyclerview in that bottom sheet.

So far I have done this

```
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
        ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG, 0
    ) {
        var selectedViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder? = null

        var offsetX: Float = 0f
        var offsetY: Float = 0f

        val popupWindow = PopupWindow(context)

        override fun getMovementFlags(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Int {
            val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0)
        }

        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            source: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean {
            val sourcePosition = source.adapterPosition
            val targetPosition = target.adapterPosition

            if (selectedViewHolder == null) {
                selectedViewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(sourcePosition)
            }

            Collections.swap(customerList,sourcePosition,targetPosition)
            custAdapter.notifyItemMoved(sourcePosition,targetPosition)
            return true

        }

        override fun onChildDraw(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {
            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG && isCurrentlyActive && selectedViewHolder != null) {
                val itemView = selectedViewHolder!!.itemView

                offsetX = if (dX < 0) 0f else dX
                offsetY = if (dY < 0) 0f else dY

                c.save()
                c.translate(offsetX, offsetY)
                itemView.draw(c)
                c.restore()
            } else {
                super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            }
        }
        override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
            if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_DRAG && viewHolder != null) {
     
                val draggedItemView = viewHolder.itemView

        
                val parent = draggedItemView.parent as? ViewGroup
                parent?.removeView(draggedItemView)

 
                val location = IntArray(2)
                draggedItemView.getLocationOnScreen(location)

      
                popupWindow.contentView = draggedItemView
                popupWindow.width = draggedItemView.width
                popupWindow.height = draggedItemView.height
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(draggedItemView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, location[0], location[1])

                super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
            }
        }

        override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
            popupWindow.dismiss()
            super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.rvCustomerList)

    binding.rvCustomerList.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(requireContext(), object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                val childView = binding.rvCustomerList.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
                if (childView != null) {
                    val viewHolder = binding.rvCustomerList.getChildViewHolder(childView)
                    itemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder)
                }
            }
        })

        override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
            return false
        }

        override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) {}

        override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) {}
    })
```

Now I can see the selected item out of the recyclerview,but behind it.